# JavaScript not working on Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I'm on Windows 7, and just upgraded IE to 10.  It works fine, except that Javascript isn't working.  I know that it is enabled, as I can go into the settings and disable it, and then I get the "no js" output.  But with it enabled, I get nothing.  No errors in the JS console.  The same script in Firefox gives me "hello".

Browser Mode is "10" and Document Mode is "Standards", though changing these doesn't yield anything different.  Here is the entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('hello');
</script>
<noscript>no js</noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

Similar results on other websites -- if I go to a page that uses Disqus comments, I just get a blank space.  If JS were disabled, Disqus would return a message saying so.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `regsvr32 jscript.dll`  and `regsvr32 jscript9.dll`

Comment: Worked for me on Windows8. Anyone else with Windows7 have the same problem? Here you can check: http://jsfiddle.net/jFrPN/

Comment: @blackbee say it to client...

Comment: i tried downloading ie10 on windows 7, by mistake, and they said, ie 10 doesnot work on this version of windows 7, after i finished the downloading..

Comment: @WooCaSh works for me on `Windows 7 IE10`

Comment: try put your code to HEAD and change DOCTYPE to another.

Comment: Tried the regsvr32 commands -- both succeeded, but no difference.

Comment: Moved the JS to HEAD -- no difference.
Tried different DOCTYPES -- no difference.
Tried jsfiddle -- it won't work at all in my IE (presumably because JS isn't working)
I'd love to remove IE, but need it for browser testing for clients who insist on using it :(

Comment: Security zones - I added my localhost domain (where my test page resides) to both intranet and trusted sites, and tried with very loose security and resetting security settings -- no difference.

Answer (score 8):

I solve this problem.
F12 -> Disable -> Script (uncheck)

Comment: I have been working on this for 2 hours. I am literally the dumbest person alive....

Comment: What might deactive Javascript checking this menu?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your problem but your markup is invalid, run it through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) to fix the problems then try again.

Comment: The only error is a missing title element, which is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: I did run it through W3C earlier - the only error it found was the <title>.  I fixed that, but it didn't yield any difference... and that alone shouldn't kill Javascript, anyway.